# Can a procedural macro derive on a struct add other derives?

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible for a procedural macro derive to add derives from other crates to the struct that it is derived upon?

#### lib.rs

```
#[derive(Combined)]
struct Foo;
```

### derive_combined.rs

```
#[macro_use] extern crate quote;
extern crate proc_macro2;
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(Combined)]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let ident = input.ident;
    let expanded = quote! {
        #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
        struct #ident;
    };

    expanded.into()
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having with this code?

Comment: @PeterHall This code intentionally doesn't work. You can't duplicate the definitions of a struct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this cannot be done conveniently with `proc_macro_derive` it can be done with `proc_macro_attribute` and seeing as the other answer already uses a derive attribute this solution may be better for your use case:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate proc_macro2;
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;

use proc_macro2::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn add_derive(_metadata: proc_macro::TokenStream, input: proc_macro::TokenStream)
                 -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let input: TokenStream = input.into();
    let output = quote! {
        #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, etc, ...)]
        #input
    };
    output.into()
}
```

Then to use this macro:

```
#[add_derive]   
pub struct TestStruct { ... }
```

Notably, attribute macros *replace* token streams whereas derive macros are suited for *appending* to token streams: [Rust Reference: Procedural Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#attribute-macros)

Answer (score 7):

With some sub-optimal work-arounds - yes!

The first issue I encountered while implementing this was the duplicate definitions for the struct - having more than one definition just won't work. To get around this, I used a custom attribute that must be specified which will be the name of the struct in the generated code:

```
#![feature(custom_attribute)]
#[macro_use] extern crate quote;
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate proc_macro2;
extern crate syn;

use syn::DeriveInput;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use proc_macro2::{Ident, Span};
use syn::{Attribute, Meta, Lit};

#[proc_macro_derive(Combined)]
#[attribute(ActualName)]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let mut input: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    for attr in input.attrs.iter().map(Attribute::interpret_meta).filter(|x| x.is_some()).map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        if &attr.name().to_string()[..] != "ActualName" { continue }
        let name;
        match attr {
            Meta::Word(ident) => { panic!("ActualName must be a name-value pair (i.e. #[ActualName = \"hey\"])"); },
            Meta::List(_) => { panic!("ActualName must be a name-value pair (i.e. #[ActualName = \"hey\"])"); },
            Meta::NameValue(meta_name_value) => {
                match meta_name_value.lit {
                    Lit::Str(lit_str) => { name = lit_str.value(); },
                    _ => { panic!("ActualName must be a string"); }
                };
            }
        };
        input.ident = Ident::new(&name[..], Span::call_site());
        let expanded = quote! {
            #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
            #input
        };

        return expanded.into()  
    }
    panic!("You must specify the ActualName attribute (i.e. #[Derive(Combined),         ActualName = \"...\"]")

}
```

After putting this code in your derive crate, the following sample of code will work:

```
#![feature(custom_attribute)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate derive_combined;

#[derive(Combined)]
#[ActualName = "Stuff"]
struct Stuff_ {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i64,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Stuff { a: 10, b: 10 }.clone());
}
```

If you have any questions about implementing this, [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html) is the tutorial I followed. If that doesn't help feel free to ask.

Comment: This a solution, but I'm not accepting it as the requirement of renaming the struct is too much of a pain point in a API.